# Camel Aggregator and completionPredicate by example

Tags: java, apache-camel, aggregator

I have the following Camel route:

```
<route id="myRoute">
    <from uri="direct:aggregator" />

    <aggregate strategy="aggregatorStrategy" completionInterval="60000" completionSize="500">
        <correlationExpression>
            <xpath>/fizz/buzz</xpath>
        </correlationExpression>

        <to uri="bean:postProcessor?method=run" />
    </aggregator>
</route>
```

As you can see it aggregates either the first 500 messages that the `<aggregator/>` receives, or all the messages within a 1 minute interval, and then sends the aggregated message on to a bean called `postProcessor`.

You can think of this aggregation logic as follows:

```
AGGREGATE UNTIL:
    We have received 500 messages
    OR
    1 minute has elapsed

THEN:
    Send to postProcessor
```

Or in pseudo-code: `aggregateUntil(weHave500Message() || 1minHasElapsed())`. I'd like to change this logic to:

```
AGGREGATE UNTIL:
    We have received 500 messages
    OR
    1 minute has elapsed
    OR
    A message is received that has a property called "fireNow" and a value of "true"

THEN:
    Send to postProcessor
```

Or, again in pseudo-code: `aggregateUntil(weHave500Message() || 1minHasElapsed() || messageHasProperty("fireNow", "true"))`.

In other words, aggregate until either of the 3 conditions are met. Any ideas how I could implement this? I have a **feeling** I can finagle this with `completionPredicate` and perhaps `eagerCheckCompletion`, but not seeing the forest through the trees here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `completionSize` and `completionInterval` together and add a `completionPredicate` to the equation, like this (you do need to use `eagerCheckCompletion="true"` because we need to test the incoming message, not the aggregated message):

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:aggregator" />
    <aggregate completionSize="500" completionInterval="60000" eagerCheckCompletion="true">
        <correlationExpression>
             <xpath>/fizz/buzz</xpath>
        </correlationExpression>
        <completion-predicate>
             <simple>${property.fireNow} == 'true'</simple>
        </completion-predicate>
        <to uri="bean:postProcessor?method=run" />
    </aggregate>
</route>
```

An alternative could be to create a compound predicate that tests all three conditions and use only that predicate as `completion-predicate` but this solution is inferior because the interval timeout is triggered by a separate thread, whereas using a compound predicate there is no thread to trigger the aggregation on timeout expiration.